# SSMS connection additional parameters

Tags: sql-server, authentication, sql-server-2012

I use `SQL Server 2012`
exist `Additional Connection Parameters` tab of `SSMS` login form when click on options button.
what's the usage of this tab.

[image]

[image]

thanks in advance.

Comment: See that button marked "Help"? Try clicking it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645898(SQL.105).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It allows you to use specify a connection string for your connection, rather than filling out the form on the Login tab.

This is useful for specifying connection properties that are not available on that tab.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645898.aspx

*Important:*
**They will not be encrypted when they are passed across the network.**

Comment: Can I use custom parameter and used then in DDL Trigger for login?